# mysql query does not give result when using date as a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM attendance 
WHERE grade = '4' 
and date = 2022-10-25
```

this is the query when I use date in it, it does not work.

The date I am getting is with php function in php

sql query in php look like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM attendance 
WHERE grade = '".$_POST['grade'][1]."' 
and date = $date`
```

but if I also hard code date in the query it does not give any result but if I remove the date query works fine.
the date type in database is date

Comment: Can you please tell what value you are getting from php in tha form of $date ??

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: Thats a really insecure way to write a query, but your problem is that a date needs to be wrapped in quotes as in `date = '$date'`

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion friends but this project only run on local network but i will keep in mind next time

Comment: Without quotes, it is evaluated as an arithmetic expression. `2022-10-25` is `1987`.

Comment: paul speiegel noted

Comment: thanks everyone actually i am new to php thats why i dont know much